# Can Linux kprobes get disabled temporarily by the kernel?

Tags: linux-kernel, ebpf, suspend, linux-namespaces, kprobe

I am monitoring illegal task namespace changes using kprobes on `wake_up_new_task()`, `do_exit()`, `begin_new_exec()`, `unshare()` and `setns()`.

For a few systemd services like `timedated` or `upowerd`, the kprobes are not always called, and namespace changes are missed, resulting in false detections.

One scenario was if kprobes were being attached while services were starting, which I addressed with an `all_probes_attached` flag in a BPF map. But I still get false detections.

Can kprobes get disabled temporarily during suspend/resume, hibernate or live kernel patches? Can I detect this from BPF or usermode?

Comment: This question would be easier to answer with a specific reproducer. Can you update the question to include one or more kprobes and a demonstration using a specific binary that fails to trigger the probes?

Comment: I can't reproduce it locally yet. I have received reports that others are getting false positives, and the only plausible reason I can find is that the probes are not called.

Comment: https://lpc.events/event/17/contributions/1609/ might be of interest. Note it's also possible for the probed functions to be inlined in some callsites and not others.

Comment: kprobe could be disabled globally (echo 0  > /sys/kernel/debug/kprobes/enabled), but you'll get a message from kmsg/dmesg. 

Another reason that kprobe won't trigger is the kprobed function is being called in wrong context (ex: atomic context, rcu or interrupt), but the 4 functions shouldn't, at least for unshare and setns since they are just syscalls.

So better check ebpf program: how the hookpoints are implemented, whether BPF map is full or not. BTW bpf_trace_printk  isn't realible.

Livepatch could prevent kprobe and vice versa, thus your ebpf will fail to load or livepatch fails.